# In what way, do Distributions (Generalised Functions) generalise the notion of function?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

In what way does the concept of Generalised Function, or Distribution, generalise the notion of function?

Is it only because we can now define derivatives in the weak sense? or is it because some other property?

Comment: Any measurable function $f$ can be seen as a distribution by associating it to the distribution $g \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}}f g$

Comment: @LukasRollier Hi, thanks for the comment. However, could you please elaborate a bit on it? I don't see its usefulness.

Comment: @LukasRollier Measurability is not sufficient!

Comment: Asking how is it useful  to generalise in this way is a question separate from your question title and body

Comment: @S.Maths, why is it not sufficient? It's been a while since I had my course of distributions

Comment: @LukasRollier In order for the map you wrote down to be well-defined, you need $f$ to be locally $L^1$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I meant how is it useful to my question... I don't see the connection between the comment and a possible answer to my question

Comment: Note: in Laurent Schwartz's autobiography, he cleartly stated that his first motivation was to give a rigourous mathemetical definition to some strange things like delta functions, used for a long time in Physics

Comment: Well to me a possible answer would be an injective map from a set of "nice functions" to the set of distributions, that is not surjective.

Comment: @CalvinKhor can you give me an example of a Generalised function, which is not a function? i.e. what type of GF are not reached by that injective map (is it an embedding?) ?

Comment: Delta distribution is not a function

Comment: I hesitated to say embedding because I feel like embeddings have to be continuous I don't know what topology to use...so lets say "all but yes".

Comment: If you're looking for a book to read about distributions, I found Duistermaat and Kolk's book  to be nice to read (i think called Distribution Theory and Applications)

Comment: @Damien could you elaborate a bit on it please? I've read the wikipedia page on the dirac measure, but I would accept your comment as an answer if it would be a bit more elaborate, specially on this « It is used to model the density of an idealized point mass or point charge as a function equal to zero everywhere except for zero and whose integral over the entire real line is equal to one. As there is no function that has these properties(...)»

Comment: the integral of a function is determined only up to equality almost-everywhere. If $f$ is any function that is 0 almost everywhere, it would have to have total integral $0$. More concretely (but not saying anything more), the Lebesgue integral assigns the function who is $+\infty$ at 0, and $0$ everywhere else the value 0. These are things you would get out of a measure theory book (which should preclude learning about distributions). I've heard that Tao has a nice measure theory book.

Comment: @CalvinKhor thanks for the comment. In my previous one, I was thinking also for posterity sake of whoelse might read this. I had that idea from measure theory, however, one of my first readings of that sentence, I wasn't sure if that density they speak about is a physical density, or a density of a measure, that would allow to write it as a integral of a function with respect to Lebesgue measure.  After rereading some times, I went for the physical interpretation, and the conclusion that there's no density possible for the Dirac measure.

Answer (score 3):

Okay. I'll give this a go. I think a good question to ask is: What do we mean by a function? In introductory real analysis, the *formalism* is that a function is a map $f:U\to \mathbb{C},$ where $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is some appropriately nice subset, say closed or open. We usually impose some regularity on $f$ such as continuity.

Now, a function in the modern sense (post-measure theory) is really an almost everywhere equivalence class of measurable maps $f:U\to \mathbb{C}$. Why? Well, the insistence on viewing things as map sort of collapses under even small perturbations. What if I change the value of $f$ at a point? Well, it doesn't matter if $f$ were continuous - we could even recover the old value! Integrals don't change either.

So what happens? Well, as long as you're in the realm of continuous maps, these are exactly the maps whose exact values at points follow from their "general behaviour" - their almost everywhere class. On the other hand, what's the value of, say, the Heaviside function at $x=0$? Answer is: It doesn't really matter, right? The genuinely useful statement is that the Heaviside function is piecewise continous, equal to $1$ on $(0,\infty)$ and $0$ on $(-\infty,0)$ - the jump at $0$ is the essential information.

With this view of what a function is, it's not that far of a stretch to say that, say, Radon measures are functions as well. It's meaningful to say that $\delta_0$ is $0$ away from $0$. It's meaningful to talk about integrals of measures. In other words, measures do have meaningful local behaviours. As such, they naturally inhabit the same properties as the almost everywhere classes of maps that form the measure theoretic functions.

Now, of course, it's *also* lovely that the notion of weak derivatives allows one to expand the theoretical foundations of partial differential equations. However, the weak derivative of a function is always a measure (identifying any $L^1_{loc}$ function $f$ with the measure $f\textrm{d}x$). I think the one good reason to consider a general distribution a generalised function is that we then get the statement "the weak derivative of a generalised function is a generalised function", so that the distributions fit into a PDE framework, and hence are useful for doing theoretical physics.

So to sum up: I think it's somewhat natural to call a Radon measure a generalised function, simply thinking about what we actually want a function to be, and distributions in general are then labelled generalised functions because it makes the theory of weak derivatives work in general.

Answer (score 1):

*In what way does the concept of Generalised Function, or Distribution, generalise the notion of function?*

It seems that Laurent Schwartz, who created the theory of distributions, give us an answer:

> By a generalization, I mean that the set of distributions is a larger set than the set of functions; every function is a particular distribution, but there are distributions which are not functions. ([1], p. 211)

*Is it only because we can now define derivatives in the weak sense? or is it because some other property?*

I would say that, when talking about distributions as generalization of functions, there are a set of fundamental properties (which are summarized in the axiomatic theory) that we should be aware of ([2], p. 4-7):

> - The set $\mathcal{D'}(I)$ of distributions on $I$ contains the set $C(I)$ of continuous functions on $I$:
>     $$C(I)\subset \mathcal{D'}(I).$$
> - The derivation in the distributional sense is an operator $D$ from $\mathcal{D'}(I)$ to $\mathcal{D'}(I)$ which extends the classical derivation on  $C^1(I)$:
>     $$\left\{\begin{aligned}
>   &Df\in\mathcal{D'}(I),&&\forall\ f\in \mathcal{D'}(I)\\
>   &Df=f',&&\forall\ f\in C^1(I)\end{aligned}\right.$$
> - $\mathcal{D'}(I)$ has no more elements than those which are needed to ensure that each continuous function is infinitely differentiable:
>     $$\text{For all $f\in \mathcal{D'}(I)$, there exists $h\in C(I)$ such that $D^n h=f$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$.}$$
> - Given $f,g\in C(I)$ and $n\in \mathbb N$, we have $Df=Dg$ if and only if $f-g$ is constant. In general:
>     $$D^nf=D^ng\;\Longleftrightarrow\; f-g\text{ is a polynomial of degree less than $n$}$$

Essentially, these properties are the way $\mathcal{D'}(I)$ generalizes $C(I)$ and the reason why the generalization is useful.

[1] [*A Mathematician Grappling with His Century*](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Mw8HCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=inauthor:%22Laurent+Schwartz%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8pvjzztLTAhWGHpAKHbbZBnYQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Laurent Schwartz.

[2] [*Introduction to the Theory of Distributions*](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=T1Hx3PMzP7oC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=%22the+system+of+axioms+contains+two+primitive+terms%22&source=bl&ots=ZkRpiN6kV1&sig=ACfU3U2JXnvSWkg0Et79lvcOgFTYJhDAbA&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjnqcPJgffmAhVQELkGHdpFDmEQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20system%20of%20axioms%20contains%20two%20primitive%20terms%22&f=false) by  J. C. Ferreira, R F Hoskins and J. Sousa-Pinto.